# Flask-sqlalchemy - Count how many times a REST endpoint(or db record) has been requested

Tags: python, mysql, rest, sqlalchemy, flask-restful

I am making a flask app which will serve with rest endpoints to the frontend. The website is for browsing guitar chords and tabs. I want to be able to count how many times a chord been requested and store this counter persistently.

the endpoint looks like this: /chord/string:chord_id

Is it a good idea to add a column to each table and increment this value each time the row is accessed? Is there another way of doing this smoothly?

I hope my question is clear. Thanks already!

Comment: What are you going to do with the count? For example will you be displaying it on the website or using it in some sort of logic to determine website content or is it just for your own analytical reasons?

Comment: I want to show a list of popular chords, artists etc in the website. It would also be nice if i could show the counter for each chord. But even just keeping most popular 10 chords-artists would be enough.

Answer (score 0):

That's how I would do it.

Take the following table, named chords:

```
+--+-----+---+-----+
|id|chord|...|count|
+--+-----+---+-----+
|01|Amaj |...|27   |
+--+-----+---+-----+
|02|Bmin |...|32   |
+--+-----+---+-----+
```

And a flask route that looks something like this:

```
@app.route('/chord/<chord_id>', methods=['GET'])
def chord_info(chord_id):
    db = MySQLdb.connect("host", "un", "pw", "db")
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM chords WHERE id = '%s'" % chord_id)
    data = cur.fetchone()
    cur.execute("UPDATE chords SET count = count + 1 WHERE id = '%s'" % chord_id)
    try:
        db.commit()
    except:
        db.rollback()
    cur.close()
    #do something with data
```

This method will give you an easily queried count that is updated everytime the endpoint is accessed.

Comment: Thanks, this is my solution so far. Another option was running a stored procedure that will increment the value, because i don't know how the solution you provide for instance will work when there are concurrent processes. I want the increment to be atomic.

Comment: @BoranKaraca If you're really concerned about a database bottleneck due to high concurrent hits on a single route, you could cache the requests and run the updates when traffic is slower.

Answer (score 0):

There is already library called flask-profiler present which gives you analytics about your endpoint and you just have to integrate with you flask app

reference link - https://github.com/muatik/flask-profiler

Below is sample image of flask-profiler about endpoint and how many times it got called 
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I think this is exactly what I am looking for the endpoint stats. It would be nice if it could provide info on each accountId in the example you provided for instance. I also want to count for each Id(for each account)